# docker execute script within another image on network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file (`version: 2`) using

`Docker version 17.06.0-ce
docker-compose version 1.15.0`

Let's say it looks like

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  container1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: container1/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - container2
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  container2:
    restart: always
    container_name: phabricator.php
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: container2/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
```

Now, I have a script in `./data` which is accessible to both containers at `/srv`. However, only `container1` has the requisite process to execute the script.

If `container2` tries to access the script, since it's an entirely separate process, it will not be able to execute the script despite having access through the host volume (e.g. the container needs `foo` to run, but `container1` is responsible for `foo` process and `container2` is responsible for `bar` process).

I want to be able to call `./path/to/bin/myscript` in `container2`, but it needs `container1`'s setup to execute. Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you add the requisite process to the setup of container 2?

Comment: As @MatTheWhale, why not club the two containers? Also what does your script actually do?

Comment: @MatTheWhale container1 runs php-fpm and container2 runs a ssh server. I'd like to separate all the processes. Right now I have nginx container, php container, and mysql container all running independently. Maybe I'm fighting the architecture though. Would you recommend clubbing php and ssh together?

Comment: @TarunLalwani as above^ Also, I'd like the logs to be separate for each container. Won't clubbing them gum that up?

Comment: @MatTheWhale the ssh server needs to execute a script that depends on php

Comment: @TarunLalwani The point of the ssh server is to pull/push git repos.